# Swift ios alamofire put request error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT at

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, httprequest, alamofire

I am trying to updat api from an api using alamofire http request my code is below. the api that i used    https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts . i cant seem to update the data and i received and an error which is Thread 1: signal SIGABRT at at line guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}

full code func updateApi(){

```
        let  params  = ["userId": 1,
                        "id": 1,
                        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
                        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit r
```

ecusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"] as [String: Any]

```
        Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", method: .put, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {


            case .success(_):
                guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
                print("Response \(json)")


                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("Error")
                break

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` and `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` are different. The latter returns something like this:

> ```
> {
>   "userId": 1,
>   "id": 1,
>   "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
>   "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
> }
> ```

It's not a JSON array but a JSON object. So your forced casting `as! [[String:Any]]?` fails.

Change the line to:

```
    guard let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] else {
        return //<- Put breakpoint here, when you find unexpected early return
    }
```

You should better not use forced casting, which makes your app crash without much useful info.

Comment: does the paramter im sending to the server are the values used to replace the data using the id?

Comment: @DurnKurvirck, the usage page suggests such behavior, but not clear enough. As it's a fake API, you should not expect all behaviors found in real APIs.

Comment: How about i a real api , let us say with the same behaviour in updating likje https://test.typicode.com/test/1?

Comment: is ther no lacking in my code? is it complete on how amalmofire put requests?

Comment: @DurnKurvirck, I do not know the _real api_, so just for the last comment. As far as I checked, I cannot find any flaws, though I haven't tested it in actual project.